# Instantiating a deployment's class from a global library in Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, classloader

In my Wildfly environment I have a global library that is used by disparate application deployments.  Those disparate application deployments include customizations for that global library.

However, that global library retains responsibility for actually instantiating those customizations.  I provide the class name that it needs and then it instantiates them via its own classloader upon initialization.

However, when I do that it throws a ClassNotFoundException.  Is there a way to "notify" the global library classloader that the package does, indeed, exist, or is my only path forward to customize the class loader in some way?

Comment: How do you have the global library defined? As a module?

Comment: I've tried defining it as a module, adding it to global bindings, setting it as a sub-deployment in jboss-deployment-structure (and vice versa).  The only way I can get it to work is if I do one 1.6GB WAR deployment, but that's a little impractical and not great when I have multiple small applications that each need access to the library.

Comment: ... and if I put my "common" libraries in one module and my app libraries in another module then it won't compile.  It's like I can either package it, but it won't run, or modularize it and it won't compile.

Comment: Do your "common" libraries include Jakarta EE components? You wouldn't want to add it as a sub-deployment, but you could add it as a module dependency on the deployment in a jboss-deployment-structure.xml https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/Developer_Guide.html#jboss-deployment-structure-file

Comment: No, they are largely DB adapters and the libraries for the Stanford NLP software.  I put those in my "common" jar, which is huge, and then I'm trying to do a skinny WAR deployment.  But because the NLP software instantiates the objects it can't seem to look back into the WAR.  I can get the WAR to see common or common to see the WAR, but I can't seem to configure them to do both.

Comment: Honestly, I'm thinking that the easiest way to make this work is to use global bindings and figure out how to let those classes see the classes inside of a standalone WAR.  I had tried taking that approach before, given that it's closer to my actual use case.  I ran into the same problem but by gut says that the solution might be simpler.

Comment: There isn't really a way to have an installed module be able to see types in a deployment. I'm not even sure how that would work.

Comment: Well, the workaround that I ended up using was to move all of the algorithmic libraries (which are small) into the WAR and kept the model libraries (which are huge) global.  A 70MB WAR is much better than a 1.6GB war.

(Thanks for the help, BTW)

Comment: Excellent. That sounds reasonable to me and I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [James Perkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152794/james-r-perkins) for the help.  It seems as though the most workable solution (I don't know if it's best) was to move the functional libraries, which constituted a fraction of the bulk of the deployment, into the WAR, but to place the model libraries in the general lib folder.  The model libraries don't need to refer back to deployed WAR so they can be as global as they need to be.  By placing the functional libraries in the WAR they are able to see the customizations that I made.